# Connecting to MySQL on localhost with --ssl-verify-server-cert returns "SSL certificate validation failure"

Tags: mysql, ssl, mariadb

My setup is running MySQL (MariaDB 5.5, an upgrade is in the queue but not within the next few months) on `db-host` and a Tomcat server on `web-host`.  Some time ago we configured database connections to use a certificate bundle for the CA.  TLS-encrypted connections worked, as best we can recall.

Recently the connections have been getting rejected.  I logged on to `db-host` and attempted to connect:

```
db-host> mysql -h localhost -u dbuser -p --ssl-ca=/etc/pki/bundle-of-certs.crt --ssl-verify-server-cert
Enter password: (correct password entered)
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: SSL certificate validation failure
```

When I connected to the database *without* `ssl-verify-server-cert`, the connection succeeded.  But `ssl_cipher` was blank.  I have confirmed that `ssl_ca` is set to this certificate file, and `ssl_cert` and `ssl_key` are set to the correct certificate and key files for `db-host`.

The file `/etc/pki/bundle-of-certs.crt` contains several CA certificates.  This file hasn't changed in several months, and the file contains multiple valid (and some expired) certificates.

I have confirmed that the server certificate file is valid:

```
db-host> openssl verify -CAfile /etc/pki/bundle-of-certs.crt /etc/pki/db-host.crt
/etc/pki/db-server.crt: OK
```

I have also used `openssl x509 ....` to confirm that `db-host.crt` contains the expected CN and SANs for `db-host`.

What have I not checked, or what can I do to fix this?

(Side note: The original issue is a web app establishing a TLS encrypted connection fails with `SSHHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)`.  I believe this is due to the certificate validation failure; if I'm wrong about this, at least I'll fix the certificate validation.)

#### Update  (in reply to Georg Richter)

I connected with `mysql -h db-host -u user --ssl-verify-server-cert ....`.  I again got `SSL certificate validation failure`.

Just to double check, I ran `show variables like '%ssl%';`

```
| Variable_name | Value
+---------------+--------------
| have_openssl  | YES
| have_ssl      | YES
| ssl_ca        | /etc/pki/bundle-of-certs.crt
| ssl_capath    | (blank)
| ssl_cert      | /etc/pki/db-host.crt
| ssl_cipher    | (blank)
| ssl_key       | /etc/pki/db-host.key
```

#### Update 2

```
db-host> mysql -u user -h db-host -p --ssl
Enter password:
MariaDB [(none)]: \s
SSL:    Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384

MariaDB> show variables like 'ssl_cipher'
| ssl_cipher    | (blank)
```

Those query results do not agree........

I went back and connected with `--ssl-ca --ssl-cert --ssl-key` on the command line with their correct values.  Just like this test, `\s` reported an RSA cipher in use but `show variables` didn't.  Whiskey tequila flaming-moe??

(Update 2.1)
I double checked the server certificate.  `X509 Subject Alternative Name` includes `DNS: db-host.foo.bar.baz, DNS:db-host, DNS:localhost`.  I conclude that connecting with the full hostname, short hostname, and localhost are all equivalent from the certificate point of view.

#### Update 3

I found a useful article at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-setup-mariadb-ssl-and-secure-connections-from-clients/.  It showed me that a status cipher can be present with `ssl_cipher` being blank.  From that I ran:

```
> show status like 'ssl_version';
| Ssl_version     | TLSv1.2
> show status like 'ssl_cipher';
| Ssl_cipher      | DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
> show variables like 'ssl_cipher';
| Ssl_cipher      | (blank)
```

I now suspect that my initial question was valid, but I've been searching in the wrong direction for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer, but too long for a comment...

**General:**

As you have already noticed, MariaDB 5.5 has not been supported for several years and has outdated technology, especially when it comes to TLS/SSL:
Several vulnerabilities are not fixed. If the server uses Yassl instead of OpenSSL then the vulnerable SSLv3 protocol is still supported, TLS Protocol > 1.1 is not supported and handshake errors are hard to debug since Yassl does not send back the required alerts but closes the connection with an unencrypted error message.

Building 5.5 with a more recent OpenSSL version will not work, since OpenSSL 1.1.x support was added in MariaDB 10.3.

**Some comments/questions:**

- Which TLS library does the server use?

  `SHOW VARIABLES like 'have%ssl'`

  If have_openssl=YES, then is uses OpenSSL
- Certificate verification

  In 5.5 TLS error messages aren't really verbose. If you log into host 'localhost' but the server certificate
  contains 'db-host' in it's CN, [comparison of host names](https://github.com/MariaDB/server/blob/5.5/sql-common/client.c#L1930) will fail.
- Error message: "No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled ...."

  Very likely your application requires a newer protocol (TLSv1.0 and TLS v1.1 are disabled e.g. in recent Java versions), and
  the server doesn't support it.

  To check this, capture the traffic between web and database server and analyze
  the handshake packet with Wireshark's SSL dissector. The first client hello packet should contain the minimum supported TLS version of the client, server hello packet contains the minimum supported version of the server.

Comment: I have updated my question in reply to your comments.  OpenSSL is available, connecting with `-h db-host` makes no changes, and I'm reasonably certain TLSv1.0 is supported.  I can't confirm that TLS is available until I establish an encrypted connection.......

Comment: Can you try to connect with --ssl instead of  --ssl-verify-server-cert ? If it works which cipher is in use (just type \s after you've  connected) ?

Comment: Updated.  I had forgotten about `\s` -- and it gave me a different answer.

Comment: Did mentions get disabled?  I tried tagging Georg Richter in my reply comment, but the system deleted the tag.

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ssl_cipher' is always blank, unless you started the server with --ssl_cipher option or specified it in your configuration file.